# Why when saving to Settings radio button states it keep loading the first radio button state and not the last radio button state changed?

Tags: c#, wpf

When loading :

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
radioButtonWatchDirectory.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchDirectory;
radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchFile;
checkBoxIncludeSubdirectories.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeSubDirectories;
textBoxFileDirectory.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;
        }
```

When setting and saving :

```
private void radioButtonWatchFile_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchFile = (bool)radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

    

private void radioButtonWatchDirectory_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchDirectory = (bool)radioButtonWatchDirectory.IsChecked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

When running the application once i checked true the Watch File radio button no matter if i check the Watch Directory radio button next time i will run the application the Watch File radio button will be checked. like it's not remembering changing it to the Watch Directory radio button.

The Include Subdirectories is working fine.

[image: Radio buttons]

I tried this when loading :

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            radioButtonWatchDirectory.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.RadiosTesting;
            radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.RadiosTesting;
            checkBoxIncludeSubdirectories.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.IncludeSubDirectories;
            textBoxFileDirectory.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.BrowseFolderDialog;
        }
```

When saving :

```
private void RadiosTests(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if((bool)radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.RadiosTesting = (bool)radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            if((bool)radioButtonWatchDirectory.IsChecked)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.RadiosTesting = (bool)radioButtonWatchDirectory.IsChecked;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

but always the radioButtonWatchFile is checked when running the application again.

Comment: Saving the state of multiple RadioButtons in a group is redundant. You should only save which button is checked, the others are automatically unchecked.

Comment: From the above comment if you were using checkboxes then you may want to track each items checked status, but radio buttons can only have 1 checked at a time.

Comment: @Clemens but when loading it keep loading the first radio button state as true.  i will up date my question.

Comment: @Brad i got the idea but not how to do it yet.  updated my question with what i tried.

Answer (score 1):

When a radio button is unchecked, the `Checked` event is not fired again. So, when you select another option, the setting of the previously checked option is not changed.

You could additionally subscribe to the [Unchecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event of each radiobutton in order to manage the state in your settings object.

However, it might be a better idea to save some consolidated state of the currently selected option, instead of saving each radiobutton state individually.

Answer to why it always selects the file option: because both IsChecked properties are assigned `true` but only one can legally be selected, the selection of the first radiobutton is reset when the second one is initialized.

If you would revert the order of loading, the other button would be selected (this code is not a solution, just a demonstration of your error the other way around)

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // reverse initialization order changes the outcome

    radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.RadiosTesting;

    radioButtonWatchDirectory.IsChecked = Properties.Settings.Default.RadiosTesting;

    // ...
}
```

---

### €dit: example of managing the radiobutton state by name with a somewhat mvvm like approach.

Suppose you create a viewmodel for your mode selection:

```
// consider linking this viewmodel to your settings somehow
class ModeViewModel
{
    public string SelectedMode { get; set; }

    public bool WithSubdirectories { get; set; }
}
```

In your groupbox, listen to `Checked` events and establish a property to maintain your selected RadioButton state => `Tag` in this example. The checked event handler will be responsible for setting the `Tag` depending on the actual RadioButton selection. When a new selected RadioButton is assigned, the ModeViewModel is updated accordingly.

```
<GroupBox Name="ModeGroup" Header="Mode"
          ToggleButton.Checked="RadioButtonChecked"
          Tag="{Binding SelectedMode, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RadioButton Name="WatchFile" Content="Watch File"/>
        <RadioButton Name="WatchFolder" Content="Watch Directory"
                     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

        <CheckBox Content="Include Subdirectories" IsChecked="{Binding WithSubdirectories}"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Checked event handler that maintains the `Tag` state depending on the selected RadioButton.Name

```
private void RadioButtonChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is RadioButton rb && sender is GroupBox gb)
        gb.Tag = rb.Name;
}
```

Load the selected radiobutton state from a string, containing the name of a RadioButton.

```
// Initialize the datacontext with your ModeViewModel
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ModeGroup.DataContext = new ModeViewModel();
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Load from your settings instead
    var selectedMode = nameof(WatchFolder);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedMode) &&
        LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(ModeGroup, selectedMode) is RadioButton checkedElement)
    {
        checkedElement.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

If you tweak this example and actually use your settings as initialization source and backing store of your viewmodel, this should work for your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Working solution.

```
void radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)radioButtonWatchFile.IsChecked)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchFile = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchDirectory = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchFile = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.RadioButtonWatchDirectory = true;
            }
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Comment: This is a bad solution, because saving multiple setting values for a single RadioButton group is redundant. A single value, e.g. the name of the checked RadioButton, or some enumeration value, would be sufficient.

Comment: @Clemens Im not at home now. I'm Yosi Ashbel. The two radio buttons are not group they are in a groupbox.  I don't remember i created a RadioButton group.

Comment: They are in the same group by default. Otherwise you could check both at the same time.

Comment: @Clemens i updated my solution answer. is that a good solution ? (it's working)

Comment: No, of course not. Imagine you have 10 Radiobuttons instead of just two.

Comment: @Clemens i tried to google and didn't find how to do it. can you show me please ?

Comment: i need to loop all over the radio buttons ? i'm confused.